# Query for last record with identical values in a continuous block

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

In SQLite, I have a table `datatable` of the following format:

```
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
|       timestamp       |  x  |  y  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
| "2015-01-30 23:00:00" |  1  |  1  |
| "2015-01-30 22:00:00" |  2  |  2  |
| "2015-01-30 21:00:00" |  2  |  2  |
| "2015-01-30 20:00:00" |  2  |  2  |
| "2015-01-30 19:00:00" |  3  |  3  |
| "2015-01-30 18:00:00" |  4  |  4  |
| "2015-01-30 17:00:00" |  2  |  2  |
+-----------------------+-----+-----+
```

I want to extract the oldest record (by timestamp) in a continuous block, with `x,y` values matching the `x,y` values of the second most recent entry. I have a working query (see end of post), but it is very inefficient with multiple sub-queries. I know there must be a better way.

Using my sample table above:

1. Search coordinates `x,y` must match `2,2` from the second most recent entry (timestamp = '2015-01-30 22:00:00')
2. Record must come from the continuous block of identical `x,y` (`22:00`-`20:00`), but not from any earlier records that also have coordinates `2,2` (i.e. `17:00`)
3. Expected value is the oldest record in this `2,2` block, or `20:00`

Here is the query I have so far. It works, but can be slow for large tables - especially with the string concatenation.

```
-- find oldest time in continuous block that matches coordinates of interest
select min(timestamp) from datatable
where timestamp > (
    -- find most recent time that does not match coordinates of interest
    select max(timestamp) from datatable
    where timestamp < '2015-01-30 23:00:00'
    and x || ' | ' || y != (
        -- find coordinates of interest (2nd most recent record)
        select x || ' | ' || y
        from datatable
        where timestamp < '2015-01-30 23:00:00'
        order by timestamp
        limit 1
        -- returns 2 | 2
    )
    -- returns '2015-01-30 19:00:00
)
-- returns '2015-01-30 20:00:00 (which is the expected result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to remove the string concatenation:

```
select min(timestamp), x, y
from datatable
where timestamp > (select max(timestamp)
                   from datatable
                   join (select x, y
                         from datatable
                         order by timestamp desc
                         limit 1 offset 1) as second
                   on datatable.x <> second.x
                   or datatable.y <> second.y
                   where timestamp < (select timestamp
                                      from datatable
                                      order by timestamp desc
                                      limit 1 offset 1))
```

With an index on `timestamp`, both queries should not be too bad.

The fastest way would probably to search for the end of the block in the application, i.e., read the results of this query:

```
select timestamp, x, y
from datatable
order by timestamp desc
limit -1 offset 1
```

and stop when the `x,y` values change.